# ASP.NET core get URL bindings

Tags: asp.net-core

After a ASP.NET core webhost has started I would like to get its binding URLs (i.e. "http://0.0.0.0:5001", "https://192.168.42.42:8081", etc.). So the URLs it has bound to after processing all that configuration stuff.

How can I do this?

Note: I am not processing a request. The server should just log it or send the information elsewhere. I find lots of information on how to set *URLs* but I would like to ask the host what it has bound to instead of asking the configuration what it should have bound to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var server = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServer>();
var addresses = server.Features?.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>()?.Addresses;

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", addresses)); // will write "http://localhost:5000"
```

Thanks to source of [WebHost class](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/80ae7f056c08b740820ee42a7df9eae34541e49e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/WebHost.cs#L228-L230)

Comment: This works. Not sure if it will reflect all active bindings but at least it should reflect all addresses it tried to bind to.

Comment: I can confirm it works with both SSL and non-SSL bindings in .Net6.0