# ASP.Net Core Get IIS Bindings Domain Names

Tags: asp.net-core

With IIS Manager I made some bindings to mij website. Now I want to list all bindings that are binded on the website itself, how can I do that?

I thought this post should be helpful, but this doesn't give the domainnames (only some IP addresses): [ASP.NET core get URL bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180473/asp-net-core-get-url-bindings)

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use  [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration/11.1.0?_src=template)  package to help you achieve your requirement.

We could get the binding information based on your IIS asp.net core web site's site name.

Since we couldn't directly get the IIS web site name in asp.net core, we will use try to get the IIS application pool identity instead.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

API controller:

```
[HttpPost("GetIISBinding")]
public ActionResult GetIISBinding()
{
    var re = GetBindings();
     return Ok(re);
}

private   IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetBindings( )
{
    // Get the Site name
    //string siteName = _IConfiguration["ASPNETCORE_APPL_PATH"];
    string name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
 
    string siteName = name.Split(@"\")[1];

    // Get the sites section from the AppPool.config
    Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationSection sitesSection =
        Microsoft.Web.Administration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection(null, null, "system.applicationHost/sites");

    foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement site in sitesSection.GetCollection())
    {
        // Find the right Site
        if (String.Equals((string)site["name"], siteName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {

            // For each binding see if they are http based and return the port and protocol
            foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement binding in site.GetCollection("bindings"))
            {
                string protocol = (string)binding["protocol"];
                string bindingInfo = (string)binding["bindingInformation"];

                if (protocol.StartsWith("http", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    string[] parts = bindingInfo.Split(':');
                    if (parts.Length == 3)
                    {
                        string domian = parts[2];
                        string port = parts[1];
                        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(protocol, domian + ":" + port);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Update:

Add application pool identity permission.

Notice: This may make your server un-security. Normally, we don't suggest you directly add this permission.

1.Open the applicationhost.config folder: `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\`

2.Right click the applicationhost.config file and select properties.

3.Click security

5.Click the "Edit" and then "Add" button
Click the "Locations" button and make sure you select the local machine. (Not the Windows domain if the server belongs to one.)

6.Enter "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" in the "Enter the object names to select:" text box. (Don't forget to change "DefaultAppPool" here to whatever you named your application pool.)

7.Click the "Check Names" button and click "OK".

8.Set the enough permission to that application pool.

9.Restart the site and try again.

Comment: Thanks. It's close to the solution I think, but when I execute this code I get "Capturing the property value threw an exception: UnauthorizedAccessException". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please tell me you run this application on the IIS or else?

Comment: The website runs on IIS indeed

Comment: You should add the enough permission for your IIS application pool identity. Please refer to my update reply to add permission to applicationhost.config file.